# xsl trying to add a hyperlink to multiple urls

Tags: xml, xslt, hyperlink

I am trying to create a hyperlink for the 2 urls in the below xml.
my input xml message is this:

```
<comment xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <biid>
        311
    </biid>
    <addComment>
        &lt;p&gt;www.test.com works another www.test.com doesn&amp;#39;t work&lt;/p&gt;
    </addComment>
</comment>
```

when i put the xml message through the xsl as stated below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" />
    <xsl:template match="*/addComment">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="contains(.,'http://')=true()">
                <addComment>
                    <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(.,'http://')" />
                    <xsl:value-of select="'&amp;lt;a target=&amp;quot;_blank&amp;quot; href=&amp;quot;'"  disable-output-escaping="yes" />
                    <xsl:choose>
                        <xsl:when test="not(contains(substring-after(.,'http://'),' '))">
                            <xsl:value-of
                                select="concat('http://',substring-before(substring-after(.,'http://'),'&lt;'))" />
                        </xsl:when>
                        <xsl:otherwise>
                        <xsl:value-of
                                select="concat('http://',substring-before(substring-after(.,'http://'),' '))" />
                        </xsl:otherwise>
                        </xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:value-of select="'&amp;quot;&amp;gt;'" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
                    <xsl:choose>
                        <xsl:when test="not(contains(substring-after(.,'http://'),' '))">
                            <xsl:value-of
                                select="concat('http://',substring-before(substring-after(.,'http://'),'&lt;'))" />
                        </xsl:when>
                        <xsl:otherwise>
                            <xsl:value-of
                                select="concat('http://',substring-before(substring-after(.,'http://'),' '))" />
                        </xsl:otherwise>
                    </xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:value-of select="'&lt;/a&gt;'" />
                    <xsl:value-of
                        select="concat(' ',substring-after(substring-after(.,'http://'),' '))" />
                </addComment>

            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="contains(.,'www.')=true()">
                <addComment>
                    <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(.,'www.')" />
                    <xsl:value-of select="'&amp;lt;a target=&amp;quot;_blank&amp;quot; href=&amp;quot;'"  disable-output-escaping="yes" />
                    <xsl:choose>
                        <xsl:when test="not(contains(substring-after(.,'www.'),' '))">
                            <xsl:value-of
                                select="concat('http://www.',substring-before(substring-after(.,'www.'),'&lt;'))" />
                        </xsl:when>
                        <xsl:otherwise>
                        <xsl:value-of
                                select="concat('http://www.',substring-before(substring-after(.,'www.'),' '))" />
                        </xsl:otherwise>
                        </xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:value-of select="'&amp;quot;&amp;gt;'" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
                    <xsl:choose>
                        <xsl:when test="not(contains(substring-after(.,'www.'),' '))">
                            <xsl:value-of
                                select="concat('http://www.',substring-before(substring-after(.,'www.'),'&lt;'))" />
                        </xsl:when>
                        <xsl:otherwise>
                            <xsl:value-of
                                select="concat('http://www.',substring-before(substring-after(.,'www.'),' '))" />
                        </xsl:otherwise>
                    </xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:value-of select="'&lt;/a&gt;'" />
                    <xsl:value-of
                        select="concat(' ',substring-after(substring-after(.,'www.'),' '))" />
                </addComment>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <addComment>
                    <xsl:apply-templates />
                </addComment>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

But the result xml only has one url hyperlinked:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><comment xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <biid>
        311
    </biid>
    <addComment>
        &lt;p&gt;&lt;a target=&quot;_blank&quot; href=&quot;http://www.test.com&quot;&gt;http://www.test.com&lt;/a&gt; works another www.test.com doesn&amp;#39;t work&lt;/p&gt;
    </addComment>
</comment>
```

The first www.test.com is hyperlinked the second www.test.com is not. How can i manage to achieve that both of them are hyperlinked?

Comment: Which XSLT processor are you using?

Comment: @michael i am using the ibis adapter framework this framework uses the xalan xslt processor.

Comment: Why does your stylesheet say `version="2.0"` then? Xalan is an XSLT 1.0 only processor. -- Incidentally, if you can, you would be well advised to move to an XSLT 2.0 processor, where you can use regex - otherwise you will have a lot of "interesting" work trying to process a mix of  `http:`, `www.` and `http://www.`.

Comment: why don't you use  replace() in xslt 2.0

Comment: @michael thank you for your advice i will take your advice and look for a solution in xslt 2.0. i am guessing the solution can be More simple with 2.0? Wouldn't you agree?

Comment: @fasln01 Of course I agree - that's why I suggested it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to process more than one URL in the provided string, you will have to use a **recursive** template.

Here's a simplified example you could use as your starting point:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="addComment">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:call-template name="URLs-to-links">
            <xsl:with-param name="text" select="."/>
        </xsl:call-template>    
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="URLs-to-links">
    <xsl:param name="text"/>
    <xsl:param name="open" select="'www.'"/>
    <xsl:param name="close" select="' '"/>
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="contains($text, $open) and contains(substring-after($text, $open), $close)">
            <xsl:value-of select="substring-before($text, $open)"/>
            <xsl:text>&lt;a target="_blank" href="</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="$open"/>
            <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(substring-after($text, $open), $close)"/>
            <xsl:text>"&gt;</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="$open"/>
            <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(substring-after($text, $open), $close)"/>
            <xsl:text>&lt;/a&gt; </xsl:text>
            <!-- recursive call -->
            <xsl:call-template name="URLs-to-links">
                <xsl:with-param name="text" select="substring-after(substring-after($text, $open), $close)"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:value-of select="$text"/>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```